# How to filter search collection only if resource has specific attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, elasticsearch, tire

I am using **Elastic Search** and **Tire** in searching.

I created Search class for searching across all my models.

```
class Link < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  tire.mapping do
    indexes :id, :type => 'string', :index => :not_analyzed
    indexes :app_id, :type => 'string', :index => :not_analyzed
    indexes :title, analyzer: 'snowball', boost: 100
  end

  def to_indexed_json
    to_json(
      only: [:id, :app_id, :title]
    )
  end    
end

class Search
  def results
    search = Tire.search [:questions, :answers, :links, :events] do
      query { string "#{term}" }
    end
    search.results
  end
end
```

The case is to return only items from Apps `12` and `13`.

So i tried to filter all results using `search.filter :and, must: {term: {app_id: [12, 13]}}` but only `questions`, `links` and `answers` have `app_id` attribute. And I would like also return all `events`.

How will be good patern to do that?

**EDIT:**
For now something like below works for me:

```
multi_search = Tire.multi_search do
  search :without_app, indices: [:events, :past_events, :reviews] do
    query { match :_all, "#{term}" }
  end
  search :with_app, indices: [:questions, :answers, :links, :service_providers] do
    query do
      filtered do
        query { match :_all, "#{term}" }
        filter :terms, app_id: app_ids
      end
    end
  end
end
multi_search.results[:with_app].to_a + multi_search.results[:without_app].to_a
```

Comment: I opened github issue in ``Tire`` gem: https://github.com/karmi/tire/issues/551

Comment: Please use _either_ Github issues _or_ StackOverflow questions, it dissolves the discussion otherwise...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good pattern could be to use the `multi_search` method, if you want to segmentize results:

```
require 'tire'

Tire.index('questions') do
  delete
  store type: 'question', app_id: 1, title: 'Question test 1'
  store type: 'question', app_id: 2, title: 'Question test 2'
  store type: 'question', app_id: 3, title: 'Question test 3'
  refresh
end

Tire.index('links') do
  delete
  store type: 'link', app_id: 1, title: 'Link test 1'
  store type: 'link', app_id: 2, title: 'Link 2'
  store type: 'link', app_id: 3, title: 'Link test 3'
  refresh
end

Tire.index('events') do
  delete
  store type: 'event', title: 'Event test 1'
  store type: 'event', title: 'Event test 2'
  store type: 'event', title: 'Event 3'
  refresh
end

multi_search = Tire.multi_search do
  search :all, indices: [:questions, :links, :events] do
    query { match :_all, 'test' }
  end
  search :rest, indices: [:questions, :links] do
    query do
      filtered do
        query { all }
        filter :terms, app_id: [1, 2]
      end
    end
  end
end

puts "ALL:  " + multi_search.results[:all].map(&:title).inspect
puts '---'
puts "REST: " + multi_search.results[:rest].map(&:title).inspect
```

Comment: I edited question with solution wich helps me. But maybe is more efficient way to do it.

Comment: You're combining the two arrays, keeping duplicates -- if that's fine, it's a good solution.